# How old is Perl's "Plain Old Documentation" (POD) format and why was it called "old" initially?

Tags: history

I recently wondered how the "old" came into the "Plain Old Documentation" of Perl's documentation format "POD". Was it named like this from the beginning? If so, why was it considered old back then?

What I figured out so far:

- POD seems to have been introduced during the 5.00x times as the oldest Perl 5.x tar ball I could find was [perl5.004.tar.gz](https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl5.004.tar.gz) and it contained at least one POD file from October 1996.

  In the [same directory](https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/) there are also hashsum files for Perl 5.003, but the tar ball itself is missing.
- The [Perl 4.036 tar ball](https://www.cpan.org/src/unsupported/4.036/perl-4.036.tar.gz) didn't have any POD, at least there was no file ending in `.pod` and an `egrep -r '^='` yielded nothing POD-like. The tar ball as a last-modified time stamp from February 1994.
- According to [perldoc perlhist](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html#THE-RECORDS), 5.000alpha1 was released on 1993-Jul-31 and 5.000 is from 1994-Oct-17.

I currently assume that POD wasn't invented after 5.000, so I think the term "Plain Old Documentation" must have been coined around 1993/1994.

One colleague suggested that the "old" refers to POD being a plain text format in comparison to all the binary formats common for word processing back then (Works, Word, Rich Text Format, etc.).

Anyone knows more details or can confirm some of the suspicions I mentioned?

Comment: "plain old" is a common English idiom meaning "ordinary", so your penultimate paragraph sounds about right.

Comment: It is very much in the spirit of [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) but around 10 years older than markdown. [Real programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Programmer_syndrome) don't use binary formats for documentation unless forced to by "management".

Comment: @manassehkatz: That's known, obvious and wasn't the question. ;-) (JFTR: I know POD for longer than I know Markdown. But despite I had to use Perl 4 about 20 years ago, I can't remember when I first stumbled over POD. But it must have been about 15 to 20 years ago. :-)

Comment: Pedantic comment of little objective worth: RTF isn't a binary file format. It's text and scoped text-based tags, even if the tags can be hard for a human to parse.

Comment: @AxelBeckert Just my first comments as I started to look into POD. I never heard of it before and last used Perl in any substantive way ~ 12 years ago - and not enough to bother with much documentation (that nobody except me would have read anyway).

Comment: @Tommy Absolutely true. I used RTF years ago for a project to generate some Word files automatically. (Since then transitioned to generating PDFs directly). It is definitely NOT binary in the sense that it is readable 7-bit text. But from a complexity standpoint, it might as well be binary.

Comment: @manassehkatz: Oh, sorry, got that wrong then. Thought you wanted to explain to me what POD is.

Comment: @Tommy: Indeed. I though vaguely remember it to contain also embedded binary stuff (Images? Fonts?) or at least being close to unreadable for human beings.

Comment: @Tommy What I used to with RTF was make my own "tags" using a string not found in general text and not found in the standard internals of RTF and then read the file and replace the tags with my own text. Essentially a mail-merge. Typical binary formats (don't know about Word because I've never read any detailed documentation, but I do have official Developer documentation for the WordPerfect formats) have positional indexes within the document so if you change length of an embedded string the file becomes unusable.

Comment: @AxelBeckert Well, I'd as well go for the 'plain old' interpretation here. No proof though. It might also be good to add links to examples, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Tommy Well, the definition as binary being different from text in itself is not as exact as one might assume. After all, what's one charsets text is a different ones control character. And IIRC there are even MS-DOS .COM files (whoch are no doubt binary) known to only use printable characters.

Comment: @manassehkatz Jup, did the same when converting documentation files maintained in a mainframe system. Extract to a PC and then converting them to RTF via XSLT :))

Comment: @RossRidge: Huh? Where am I saying something against Toby Speight's comment? In contrary, I upvoted it. And of course am I asking these questions. Why should I remove them?

Comment: Sorry my mistake I misread who you we replying to.

Comment: Re "plain old" - perhaps the first use I heard of such a phrase was as part of [POTS](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/12148/plain-old-telephone-service-pots), for Plain Old Telephone Service; that became a useful term when digital services such as ISDN started to appear.  Nowadays, "plain old" is as much a tech cliché as "considered harmful" was to a previous era.

Comment: @another-dave maybe Yet Another Documentation Format was already taken? [@]Raffzahn I'd probably argue it is text because all tags are composed of characters from the ASCII set, selected as a function of the English-language semantic meaning of the tag. But, yeah, bytes are just bytes. And the thing isn't exactly readable like Markdown or POD so another argument that might contradict mine is that, fine, intentions are one thing, but we're judging results.

Comment: You may want to ask tchrist directly as I believe he was involved - https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist

Comment: Sorry, but no, RTF files are not readable 7-bit ASCII files.  They're **un**readable 7-bit ASCII files. I'm pretty sure Randal Schwartz asserted the ordinary meaning the one time I heard him talk live.  But that was more than a decade ago, so it would be easy for me to remember wrong.

Comment: Ooo! Flashback!  Back in the late 70s/early 80s we used a document production system called "[Scribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribe_(markup_language))" at Carnegie-Mellon University, and output that was formatted for the [Diablo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_630) printer was saved to a `.POD` file.  "POD" stood for "Prince of Darkness."

Comment: Who's voting to close this as off-topic and, more importantly, why? I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Thanks! I've deliberately chosen retrocomputing (over e.g. stackoverflow), because this question doesn't fit anywhere else better. And I don't see why it would be off-topic (which is what the two voters argue about), either. It's software archaeology, just not hardware archaeology and not about running old stuff, just about its history.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This commit](https://github.com/schacon/perl/commit/a0d0e21ea6ea90a22318550944fe6cb09ae10cda) (recreated much later) introduces POD files, in version 5.000; its parent, corresponding to alpha 9, doesn’t have them, so it appears they were introduced between alpha 9 in May 1994 and the 5.000 release in October 1994.

[This message on `comp.lang.perl`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.perl/rSvC42jEiWs/UsOiH26QYTYJ) suggests that POD was a reaction to `roff` (and its availability, or lack thereof, on various platforms), among other reasons:

> I'm very well aware of this but it requires nroff (not readily
>   available on VMS, MS-DOS, AmigaDOS etc).
>
> This is one of the reasons Larry moved away from *roff format for the
>   Perl 5 documentation. The P in pod can also stand for portable.

and [this message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.perl/rSvC42jEiWs/DBlyx7BGmSUJ) quotes another message (not available in the archives) which says

> > Sorry if I appear to be a yokal, but what is this pod stuff anyway?
> >
> > I've never heard of it before now.
>
> plain old documentation.  **it's a format larry designed recently
>   for use by perl5**.  the ideas are it's easy of use, and that you
>   write some translator from pod to some other markup language
>   (two of these exist currently - pod2man and pod2html), so you
>   can read it how ever you want.

(The highlighting is mine, or rather Axel’s.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the addition of the Usenet posting to this answer. Actually [a few postings later, there's written much of what I wanted to know](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.perl/rSvC42jEiWs/DBlyx7BGmSUJ). While that posting is just citing another (seemingly not archived) posting, it still contains the relevant parts: "it's a format larry designed recently for use by perl5."